# Pulling the Code rather than the Access Token from a React Native Facebook Sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, react-native

When signing into Facebook through React-Native, is it possible to pull a the code used to generate additional access tokens (as one typically would on a server, outlined [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm))?

My goal is to pass this code to a Rails backend that can then generate its own access token to store user data and generate a JWT from that data for its secure API endpoints that the React-Native app would use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code can be exchanged for an access token only once, you can not use it to generate “additional” access tokens once it has been used. And I don’t see any need to do so – if you already have an access token, then just use it for your requests. Getting a second one would not make anything more secure.

Comment: Ah I see, I was incorrect about the way the code worked.

What would be a better way to handle this "handshake" between client and server so my server can make requests on behalf of the user, without compromising the access token? It seems like poor practice to just send whatever the token is to my server as a generic post request.

Comment: Just do it via HTTPS, then everything is fine. Tokens can't really be faked, if you make an API request or debug the token, then you'll see if it is genuine or not.